# Python, code a number with exponential decimal notation

Tags: python, numbers, format

Just formal coding question.
If I want to code a value in Python using exponential decimal notation i.e.
`my_value1= 1E-5` instead of `my_value1= 0.000001`
or
`my_value2= 1E5` instead of `my_value2= 100000`

Is there any format to do that or only the ugly way of putting all the 0s or making Python compute the value from?

```
my_value= 10**(n)
```

or writing it as string and transforming to float!

For the example of 5, it's OK to write the whole, but for number of the order of 1E30 or 1E-30 can be too ugly, and I see it pointless to make the operation of 10**(n) or the string one.

A quick search offered me nothing and I went fast through
http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html
with no obvious solution either.

I mean it's not the end of the world if it can't be done but I'm curious if that exists or not.
Thanks

Comment: What happened when you tried typing literally what you said you wanted to use as the format? (Hint: you already had it right.)

Comment: fine i tried 1E(-30) and oviously it didn't work, but 1E-30 does...

Comment: The documentation you seek is under "floating point literals" - http://docs.python.org/2.4/ref/floating.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a = 10e-50
```

Totally valid code.

Python is cool like that

Comment: +1 for noting that Python is cool.